# Loading a JavaScript Function immediately via Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm a beginner when it comes to making Chrome extensions, and in short, I want to be able to have something that executes across all web pages. In short, it's supposed to be a mouse tracker.  I get X and Y coords of the mouse on the browser. However, I'm sort of just lost. I don't know where the file saves, if it's saving, or even if it's working. The only thing that is working is the icon image, and the html pop up from my understanding.

Can anyone sort of explain what I'm doing? I've gotten this far through tutorials, but I can't edit it as well as I want.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "MouseTracker",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }

}
```

**mouseTracker.js**

```
const data = [];

let last = Date.now();
document.onmousemove = function (event) {
    const time = Date.now();
    if (time > (last + 100)) {
        const {clientX, clientY} = event;
        data.push({x: clientX, y: clientY, time});
        last = time;
    }
}

document.getElementById('finished').onclick = function () {
    const stuff = JSON.stringify(data);
    const mime = 'data:text/plain';
    downloadURI(mime + ',' + stuff, 'mouse.txt');
}


function downloadURI(uri, name) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    link.click();
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <button id="finished">
        Finish Test!
    </button>
</html>
```

Overall, the goal is to get call document.onmousemove = function (event) whenever the mouse is moved regardless of the tab. Any explanations on what my code is doing is appreciated.

Edit: The code is as is. That is ALL of the files.

Comment: Well, for one: your HTML is invalid...

Comment: @AlexMcMillan To follow up, link the files

Comment: Yeah, I just saw the head thing as I posted that. It's removed in my source code, but everything is there. That's all the code and all of the files.

Comment: "have something that executes across all web pages" -> Use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). Note you can't access global variables in content scripts, but you can track mouse positions via events from the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your question is too broad, try to get a good understanding of how chrome extensions works first and then come back here for directions in case you get stuck. Here is a good start if you have completed the tutorial for the chrome extension: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview

Read through the chrome extension API classes and methods, and through its architecture, that will help you on how to structure your extension. Many questions here in stackoverflow are present already and could give you some suggestions on how to proceed.

In my opinion in your case you might need a background.html file backed by a content script via message passing: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

To save your data you can use html5 local storage.

If you want a good video tutorial instead check this out, you might find it unclear at first but after you read through the documentation it will get more sense https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3McMaHvlBY

Good luck with your project